# I am receiving this error when trying call the in_degree function in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

> AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'in_degree'

This is the error I am receiving. Below is my code

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

sources = df["Source"]
destinations = df["Destination"]

Graph1 = nx.DiGraph()

Graph1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,"Source","Destination")

in_degree = Graph1.in_degree()
```

Comment: please add code and more information

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing the code?

Comment: sorry! added code

Comment: `Graph` is an edge list, returned in the previous statement.  That has no method `in_degree`.  You're overloading your variable names.

Comment: so what can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: @MS0798 Rename it to something other than `Graph`

Comment: i did, still doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

`Graph1` is not a `DiGraph`. `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` will by default create and undirected graph, i.e., a `Graph`--that's why you get that error. Your line of code `Graph1 = nx.DiGraph()` essentially does nothing because `Graph1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist...` overwrites it. Instead, define the type of graph you want to create when implementing `nx.from_pandas_edgelist`:

```
nx.from_pandas_edgelist(..., create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```